# PostgreSQL - update a column value using a subquery

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, boolean, subquery

Table `countries` contains information about different countries and another column:

```
ALTER TABLE countries
ADD COLUMN three_rivers BOOL DEFAULT FALSE
```

I want to update the value for the countries that have more than 3 rivers flowing in their territory.

Table `rivers` contains information about rivers and table `countries_rivers` ensures the connection between the original tables. It has two columns, `river_id` where a `countries_rivers.river_id` is a `rivers.id` and a `countries_rivers.country_code` is a `countries.country_code`.

This selects the result I want:

```
SELECT country_code,
    COUNT(country_code) AS counter
FROM countries_rivers
GROUP BY country_code
HAVING COUNT(country_code)>3
ORDER BY counter DESC
```

How can I update `countries.three_rivers` to `counter` using a subquery?

Maybe something like `UPDATE countries SET three_rivers=1 WHERE ...`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a subquery to update.

```
WITH RiverCounts AS (
  SELECT country_code, COUNT(country_code) AS counter
  FROM countries_rivers
  GROUP BY country_code
  HAVING COUNT(country_code) > 3
)
UPDATE countries c
SET three_rivers = TRUE
FROM RiverCounts rc
WHERE c.country_code = rc.country_code;
```

Answer (score -1):

The following query should work:

```
UPDATE countries
SET three_rivers = TRUE
WHERE country_code IN (
    SELECT country_code
    FROM countries_rivers
    GROUP BY country_code
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
);
```

The subquery will get the code of countries having 3 rivers and the query will update accordingly.